# Verify CA File in PHP obtained from a Request from Python Client

Tags: php, python

I have a python Client which accesses a PHP Server . The client code is as follows:-

```
import urllib2
response=urllib2.urlopen('https://204.57.7.4/info.php',cafile="cafile.pem")
print response.read()
```

Notice that I am attaching the CA file along with urlopen. I want to validate the client request at the Server.

Now how will I access the cafile.pem in my server side which is based on PHP.

Comment: Why do you need a `cafile` for HTTP?

Comment: i am sorry. I missed the s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't submitting the CA file to the server, you are telling the python http client to check the certificate given to it BY the server against cafile.pem

Specifically, from [python's SSL documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_verify_locations) you are:

> loading a set of “certification authority” (CA) certificates used to
>   validate other peers’ certificates when verify_mode is other than
>   CERT_NONE

That is, you use the cafile to validate that the server is who it says it is. The server never receives the file and so it can't use the file to validate the client.

Comment: oh this answers it! thank you. I am trying it now with python requests. Is this is good approach?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying you are going to send the file over HTTP POST using python Requests? If so, then that seems like a reasonable route to take.

Comment: using this : r=requests.get(url,cert="cafile.pem",verify=False)

Comment: What you are doing with the above is the same as with your original code, except you now aren't actually checking anything at all due to `verify=False`. I think you want to send your cafile.pem to the server, is that correct? If so, you'll want to send the cafile.pem as data and have the PHP on the server side process the request with the cafile posted. See the Data section at http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml for some examples.

Comment: yes you have got me right. I want to send the ca file. Well you have solved it for me. Many thanks!